# Android Seekbar float values from 2.0 to 8

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi i am new for android and in my app i have one seeckBar
for measuring persons height my seeckBar min range is--->2 and max range is---->8

Here i want to show my seeckBar values like 2.0,2.1,2.5.....2.12,

After 2.12 i want to show seeckBar range is 3ft's in that way process is need going up to 8ft's

How can i do this can some one help me please

### code:-

```
try {
    CrystalSeekbar height_seeckBar = (CrystalSeekbar) view.findViewById(R.id.height_seeckBar);
    height_seeckBar.setOnSeekbarChangeListener(new OnSeekbarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(Number value) {
         long i = (long)value;
                    float finalValue = i/12;
                    total_height.setText("" + finalValue + " (ft)");
        }
    });

} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: use integer between 20 and 80

Comment: explain me with some code please because i am begginer

Comment: as @Blackbelt wrote, use values from 20 to 80 and divide by 10, about code, please do some work on the web, not so hard... BTW, it's give you one digit after the dot, like 2.2 but not 2.25 (of course you can change the range to be between 200 to 800...)

Comment: Hi i updated my code AsfK but still expected result not coming